# How to get Embed link from Openload API after Remote upload? Selenium & Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, python, chromedriver, api

im trying to use Openloads API in python, i can do a remote upload like this:

```
ol_url = driver.current_url
resp = ol.remote_upload(ol_url)
file_id = resp.get('id')
```

Now i have a file uploaded in Openload and his ID, and now i want to know the Link or the Embed of this remote uploaded file.

I have been searching info for a long time and nothing, someone can help me? Please

Answer (score 0):

By using "Check Remote Upload Status":

> https://api.openload.co/1/remotedl/status?login={login}&key={key}&limit={limit}&id={id}

The response will contain the URL link for your upload. Replace {id} with your file_id value.

For more information read the API documentation: https://openload.co/api

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple task as you have the file ID. Look at this openload url structure:

**embed url:**   `https://openload.co/embed/72fA-_Lq8Ak3/`

**direct link:**   `https://openload.co/f/72fA-_Lq8Ak3`

The difference is very simple: use **/embed/*yourfileid*** for embed and **/f/*yourfileid*** for direct link.

just replace the **file_id** with your openload file id:

```
https://openload.co/embed/file_id/
https://openload.co/f/file_id/
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the link or the embed code of a file uploaded using Openload's remote upload API, you can make use of Openload's `getFileInfo` API endpoint.

Here's how you can do it in Python using the requests library:

```
import requests

API_LOGIN = 'your_api_login'
API_KEY = 'your_api_key'
FILE_ID = 'your_file_id'

# Construct the API endpoint URL
url = f'https://api.openload.co/1/file/info?login={API_LOGIN}&key={API_KEY}&file={FILE_ID}'

# Send a GET request to the API endpoint
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the response JSON to get the file URL and embed code
json_response = response.json()
file_url = json_response['result']['url']
embed_code = json_response['result']['embed']
```

The getFileInfo API endpoint returns a JSON response that contains the file URL and the embed code in the result object. We can parse the JSON response using the `response.json()` method and extract the URL and embed code from the `result` object.